# In the schema.xml configurations should the copyField CONTENT exist along with a field CONTENT?

Tags: solr

This is from someone who has not done Solr configurations.

Are there two different CONTENT fields?

The schema I'm looking at contains a <field name="CONTENT"...> which I know to be populated from the entirety of a document.

Within the schema.xml configuration file I see several sources which are specified for the copyField.
e.g.

```
<field name="CONTENT" type='text_general' indexed='true' stored='true'>

<copyField source='ALPHA' dest='CONTENT'/>
<copyField source='BRAVO' dest='CONTENT'/>
<copyField source='CHARLIE' dest='CONTENT'/>
```

So, is this configuration done incorrectly seeing how there are 4 tag sets with CONTENT?

Should it be either or but not both (it looks like it is wrong to me)?

Comment: The schemas is perfectly valid, it just means that anything sent to the fields `ALPHA`, `BRAVO` and `CHARLIE` also gets copied into the field `CONTENT`. There is no problem having multiple fields copying into a single field, the content will just be concatenated as it gets indexed (generally there is no need to set the field as `stored="true"` since the content is available in the ALPHA/BRAVO/CHARLIE-fields and would just be duplicate data.

Comment: @MatsLindh but isn't that redundant? We are populating CONTENT and we are also populating ALPHA|BRAVO|CHARLIE. We should be able to just drop the copyField configurations being that we are setting the CONTENT in our call. It just feels like excess configurations.

Comment: Having a field be the destination of multiple fields is something you do to match different search patterns. If you all you care about is "does this text exist somewhere", then only having the content indexed into a single field is perfectly fine. If you at some time want to _only_ search in ALPHA/BRAVO/CHARLIE _without getting results from the other fields), you can't do that with a single field that contain everything. Also, if you want to _score hits in the different fields differently_, you'll need to have them as separate fields.

Comment: However, that requires you to always give the complete list of fields that you want to search, and will give different scoring based on what the field contents are - a common field will score relevancy based on _all the content from all the fields_ inside that single field, while other fields will score relevancy based on content compared to the same field in the other documents. Usually you use ALPHA/BRAVO/CHARLIE to do targetted search (for example "oh, I only want hits in address now"), while you use the catch-all (CONTENT) field to do general one field search.

Comment: But it depends on _how you want to search your content_ and how you want to control scoring and relevancy. If you only care about "this text exists somewhere in this document and all text has the same relevancy", then having a single field without the other fields work fine. There is no single correct answer, it's something you implement or don't implement based on your search requirements. However, _changing it after the fact_ is harder, since that requires you to reindex your content (submit everything to the index again), so generally you trade storage requirements for querying flexibility.

Comment: _If_ you're submitting "CONTENT" which already is a concatenated version of ALPHA/BRAVO/CHARLIE (I didn't parse that sentence in that way previously), there is no need for the copyField instructions, but if that wasn't done previously, it's probably just lingering from that old time. But in that case you can remove the CONTENT field and let it be generated on the Solr side instead.

Comment: @MatsLindh It seems that it would be best to utilize the copyField to put data into the CONTENT field and to NOT manually pass to Solr values for CONTENT programatically as we appear to do through our calls to Solr. Just let Solr do its job and set the values.

Comment: Yes - unless you want to rely on a side effect of doing it twice - since the terms in ALPHA/BRAVO/CHARLIE will have been added twice to your CONTENT field in your current solution, documents with the searched terms in those fields will actually rank higher, since they have a higher term frequency for the matched terms (i.e. `foo` appears twice instead of once because of being added twice). You can replicate that by querying A/B/C with additional weight in `qf` with edismax, but it all depends on what you want to achieve.